# Conditional Derivation for Unit Testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests that encapsulate a hardware driver (user space), the design pattern that I'm using is as follows:

```
class uio
{
    virtual uint32_t readbit(...);
    virtual bool writebit(...);
    // other driver related functions
    // ...
};

class uio_test : public uio
{
    virtual uint32_t readbit(...) override { /* don't talk to hardware, send back test data */ }
    virtual bool writebit(...) override { /* don't talk to hardware, write test data */ }
};

class spi : public uio
{
    // spi related functions
};

class i2c : public uio
{
    // i2c related functions
};
```

My questions is how to go about making spi and uio properly inherit from either uio OR uio_test depending on the module (real program vs gtest). I've looked at conditionals for example:

```
template<bool test>
class spi : public std::conditional<test, uio_test, uio>
```

and this would work in world where all objects were derived simply from the main.

```
/* main.cpp */
spi<false> s;
s.init();
s.writebit();

/* gtest_main.cpp */
spi<true> s;
ASSERT_TRUE(s.init());
ASSERT_EQ(/* read/write test bits, etc*/);
```

however the uio derived objects are used in other specialized classes throughout the program, and I cannot see a good way of conditional construction, for example:

```
class temperature_monitor
{
    createBuses();
    spi<???>* spictrl_;
};

/* perhaps derive test classes, easy since most high level objects are singletons */
temperature_monitor::createBuses()
{
    if (testmode)
        spictrl_ = new spi<true>;
    else
        spictrl_ = new spi<false>;     
}
```

Hope that's clear as mud for everyone. I'll answer a few questions before they're asked:

Q. How about pre-processor conditionals?

A. No, if possible, never.

Q. Why are you writing unit tests for low level bit banging drivers like spi?

A. Why not, there's some internal logic going on, and I'd rather catch errors in a unit test than try and debug a stupid missing 0 for a day.

Comment: A  nice example why avoiding inheritance is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a strategy pattern. `uio` provides a non-virtual interface and a pointer to an implementation. You think have a virtual interface and provide either a normal or test instance of that to the `uio` object, rather than trying to insert inheritance in the middle. Using the strategy pattern even allows you to plug in additional implementations.